# IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM

Tags: iis, tfs, continuous-integration, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Visual Studio Team service for Release Management.

While doing so I am using below operation/step to create web site.

- [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemname=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp)

[image]

This operation succeeded but the Physical Path is incorrect after this operation completes.

[image]

I have followed steps mentioned in below link

[Deploy ASP.NET apps to domain-joined machines using WinRM](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/other-servers/net-to-vm)

Comment: How did you get the machine value through $(machines)? And did you try it with port others than 5001 such as 80?

Comment: I recreated the release definition and it worked. Looks like something has cached.

Comment: did you use a queue  as an agent ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not specify the correct value of Machine.

> Specify comma separated list of machine FQDNs/ip addresses along with
>   port(optional).
>
> For example *dbserver.fabrikam.com*,
>   *dbserver_int.fabrikam.com:5986*,*192.168.34:5986*. Port when not
>   specified will be defaulted to WinRM defaults based on the specified
>   protocol. i.e.,
>
> (For WinRM 2.0): The default HTTP port is 5985, and the default HTTPS
>   port is 5986. Machines field also accepts 'Machine Groups' defined
>   under 'Test' hub, 'Machines' tab.